# How to print a single line from a dictonary in python 3

Tags: python

Beginner here writing a code in IDLE that goes like this. I need it to prompt the user to enter a stall number. Then tell the user the animal, food type, and feeding time associated with that stall. This is the code I have to accompany this.

```
stalls = {101: 'Zebras',
          102: 'Elephants',
          103: 'Geese',
          104: 'Sheep',
          105: 'Turtle',
          106: 'Cheetah',
          107: 'Giraffe',
          108: 'Capybara',
          109: 'Monkeys',
          110: 'Turkey',
          111: 'Guinea Pigs',
          112: 'Possum',
          113: 'Goats',
          114: 'Lions',
          115: 'Tigers'}

food_types = {101: 'Grass',
              102: 'Vegetables',
              103: 'Worms',
              104: 'Grass',
              105: 'Vegetables',
              106: 'Meat',
              107: 'Vegetables',
              108: 'Vegetables',
              109: 'Fruit',
              110: 'Worms',
              111: 'Fruit',
              112: 'Worms',
              113: 'Grass',
              114: 'Meat',
              115: 'Meat'}

feeding_times = {101: '0730',
                 102: '0900',
                 103: '0845',
                 104: '0930',
                 105: '0745',
                 106: '0805',
                 107: '0800',
                 108: '0808',
                 109: '0953',
                 110: '0738',
                 111: '0747',
                 112: '2000',
                 113: '1005',
                 114: '0923',
                 115: '0843'}

stall_choice =  input (int("Which animal are you looking for? Please enter stall number. "))
```

If I input 111, I am expecting an output of something like "stall number 111 eats Fruit at 0747"
How do I print a dictionary by specific line? I am aware there are other ways of creating a program like this but I am getting some practice with the use of dictionaries. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Accessing a dict's value by key? String concatenation? Printing?

Comment: You look up values in a dictionary by indexing it like `stalls[stall_choice]`, which is an expression that evaluates to the value for that key - please read up on the very basics of how dictionaries work.

Comment: if `d` is a dictionary, you can do `d[key]` and get the `value`. So for example, in your case, `stalls[101]` will return `'Zebras'`. Does this help?

Comment: You probably wouldn't store three separate `dict`s like this, instead having a single `dict` whose values are (say) tuples: `info = {101: ('Zebras', 'Grass', '0730'), ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dictionary[key]`. Also, it's `int(input())`, not `input(int())`. Take a look below:

```
# Define dictionaries
stall_choice = int(input('...'))
print(f"stall number {stall_choice} (which is {stalls[stall_choice]}), eats {food_types[stall_choice]} at time {feeding_times[stall_choice]}")
```

Here, I've used f-strings, but you could also use `.format()`.

Output:

```
stall number 111 (which is Guinea Pigs), eats Fruit at time 0747
```